# Set key to difference key when get laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-collection

I want to change my collection array key to language code.

Here is my code

```
$products = Product::has('languages')->paginate(20);
        return response()->json($products);
```

This is my relationship

```
public function languages($lang_id = null)
{
    if ($lang_id)
        return $this->hasMany(ProductLang::class)->where('lang_id', $lang_id)->first();
    return $this->hasMany(ProductLang::class);
}
```

This is what I get for now.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#613 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => App\Models\Product\ProductLang {#614 ▶}
        1 => App\Models\Product\ProductLang {#615 ▶}
    ]
}
```

Expected:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#613 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
        en => App\Models\Product\ProductLang {#614 ▶}
        zh => App\Models\Product\ProductLang {#615 ▶}
    ]
}
```

Thanks for any help..

Comment: Can you clarify how you are getting that collection of `ProductLang` since your code is showing you are querying `Product`

Comment: @Helioarch Im getting product using eager loading yea

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I have provided my answer below

Answer (score 2):

There is a collection method called [keyBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-keyby). Also, I woudn't use a conditional parameter in a relationship the way you pass `$lang_id`. I'd rather create two relationship methods.

So, you can do:

```
$products = Product::has('languages')
    ->paginate(20)
    ->getCollection()
    ->map(function ($product) {
        return $product->languages->keyBy('lang_id');
    });

return response()->json($products);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapWithKeys` collection method.

As per Laravel Documentation:

> The `mapWithKeys` method iterates through the collection and passes each
>   value to the given callback. The callback should return an associative
>   array containing a single key / value pair:

```
$keyed = $products->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
    return [$item['locale'] => $item]; // assuming 'locale' key
});

$keyed->all();
```

References:
[Laravel -> Collections -> Method mapwithkeys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-mapwithkeys)

[Laracast -> Change eloquent model relationship key](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/change-eloquent-model-relationship-key?page=0)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and remap the key of the loaded relationship after the query like so:

```
$products = Product::has('languages')->paginate(20);
foreach($products as $product){
  $product->setRelation('languages', $product->languages->mapWithKeys(function($language){
      // Assuming the code is in the attribute `language_code`
      return [$language->language_code => $language]; 
    }));
}

return response()->json($products);
```